# CSS - break line without breaking words

Tags: html, css

I am working with content management and there is issue created with line break. I am displaying some content and it not gets break in multiple lines automatically. So I used CSS property "word-wrap:break-word".

When I used it, line gets braked but it cutting words of end of line.

I want to break only line and not a word.

Is there any solution ?

HTML

```
<div class="profile_fields">
 <ul>
  <li>
    <span id="CE_profile">Description:</span>
    <span>Join us in this 90 minute presentation and learn the indications and 
          "how to" for practical topics that will improve your diagnostic and
           treatment skills with cats. 
    </span> 
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.profile_fields {
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.profile_fields > ul {
    padding: 10px;
}
.profile_fields > ul > li > span + span {
    width: 330px !important;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.profile_fields > ul > li > span + span {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    min-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 380px;
}
```

I want to break content of second span in multiple lines

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fpTwP/

Comment: It is supposed to be the natural behavior of elements. Can you show us your HTML and CSS?

Comment: Nothing can be suggested without seeing the actual code.

Comment: Html is
<li>
 <span id="CE_profile">Description:</span>
 <span>Join us in this 90 minute presentation and learn the indications and "how to" for practical topics that will improve your diagnostic and treatment skills with cats. </span>
</li>
CSS is
.profile_fields > ul > li > span + span {
    width: 330px !important;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.profile_fields > ul > li > span + span {
    display: block;
    float: none;
    min-width: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 380px;
}

Comment: I want to break content of second span in multiple lines.

Comment: Always edit your question instead of posting details in comments. And your CSS doesn't respect your HTML (`.profile_fields` is not there)

Comment: @Andrea Ligios- Please check. I have provided more details here.

Comment: I made a fiddle for you. I don't understand what the problem is, though. The lines are splitted, the words are not truncated... could you be more clear about it ? Please add the browser that is giving you the problem too. It is nice to me on FireFox...

Comment: @Andrea Ligios- Yes, links are slitted, but I don't want to truncate words. Actually I want to show one line content on multiple lines without breaking words. "word-wrap" dose it by breaking word, so it is not useful in my case.

Comment: Which words are broken ?

Comment: @Andrea Ligios- Thanks Andrea. Finally I got solution. Actually I am doing some operations on content body and then displaying it. Due to PHP function applied, content were not displaying properly and so "word-wrap" breaking words. I made change in PHP code and issue is gets resolved.          Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
   word-break: keep-all;
```

more info on word breaking in css can be found here: 
http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/word-break

Comment: Consider http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/word-break as an alternative link

Comment: i don't realy get why you want to boycot -w3schools, but anyways i changed my link

Comment: @jonasvermeulen they used to be full of inaccuracies - they got better - but there are still parts that are wrong or at least explained the wrong way. So it is often better to suggest another better source then w3schools, especially when learning there is the risk of learning bad styles. E.g. the page [JavaScript How To](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_howto.asp), while the infos are not wrong they are bad explained.